# How to manage VSTS extension keys in automated manner?

Tags: security, azure-devops, secret-key

I am using my [VSTS extension key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/auth?view=vsts#get-your-extensions-key) to [authenticate request to my service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/auth?view=vsts#net-framework). The only way to obtain the extension I know of is through the VSTS Marketplace UI, as explained in the linked doc.

My questions are:

1. Is there an automated way to access the extension key, so I can rotate it automatically?
2. When does the key expire? How can I figure this out by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Powershell RestAPI for getting the certificate:

First, you need to create Personal Access Token from your VSTS account (make sure that the PAT is for "All accessible account"), you can scope the PAT to Marketplace only or "All Scopes" - your choice.

Then use this code in Powershell:

```
# Define credentials
$credPair = "YourMailAccount:YourPAT"
$encodedCredentials = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($credPair))                        
$certificateUrl = 'https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/gallery/publishers/<YourPublisherName>/extensions/<ExtensionId>/certificates/latest'

# Call the REST API
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $certificateUrl -OutFile "ExtensionCert.txt"  -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $encodedCredentials"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding key expire, you can check it here: https://jwt.io/  or programming, such as PowerShell: [Validating JSON Web Token (JWT) with PowerShell](https://madeofthings.net/2015/10/26/validating-json-web-token-jwt-with-powershell/)